# jQuery UI: How to customize buttonset corners?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

Like the image below, how can I customize the corner of the radio buttonset of jQuery UI? Instead of have a round corner at right side of a button, how can I customize it and make it has rounded-corner at the bottom?

[image: jQuery UI buttonset]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: edit jquery-ui.css file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following jQuery after your jQuery UI script

for following example

```
<div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio"><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
  </div>
```

use this script

```
 // select last radio label
    var radio = $( "#radio" ).find('label').last();

    //update border radius
    $(radio).css('border-radius','0px 0px 4px 4px');
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI framework solution:

- Locate the first (and last control) in the buttonset
- Remove the classes `ui-corner-left` (and `ui-corner-right`)
- Add the classes `ui-corner-top` (and `ui-corner-bottom`)

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/jYxp4/)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery UI CSS, change your button which has :

```
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-br {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

to

```
.ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-right {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works! But it will change all the corner of the buttonset. So if I have a horizontal and vertical buttonset on my page, they won't display well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: i didnt say you should change the class for all buttons , i said change your button ( that you want to apply the class to ) , so that it only has corener-left , and corner-right , anyway glad you found a solution.